# Delete item in List

Tags: arrays, swiftui, grid, selection, delete-row

I have a view where I'm displaying an array of data in a List through a Grid layout.
Now, as I'd like to use the app both on MacOs and iPad, I have added a trash button to delete items in the list, but I don't know how to make it work.

Here the code I have:

```
import SwiftUI

struct RosaView: View {
    
    @State var rosa: [Rosa] = Rosa.testRosa()
    
    var stagione: String = "2023/2024"
    
    var body: some View {
       
        var rosaFiltrata: [Rosa] {
            Rosa.testRosa().filter {
                $0.stagione == stagione
            }
        }
        
        var RosaGiocatori = rosaFiltrata.sorted{$0.ruoloGiocatore > $1.ruoloGiocatore}
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            
            Text("Stagione: \(stagione)")
                .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.blue/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .padding()
            
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                List {
                    Grid(alignment: .leading) {
                        GridRow {
                            Text("Nome")
                            Text("Cognome")
                            Text("Ruolo")
                            Text("Data di nascita")
                            Text("Età")
                        }
                        .bold()
                        Divider()
                        
                        ForEach (RosaGiocatori, id: \.self) { giocatore in
                            GridRow {
                                Text(giocatore.nomeGiocatore)
                                Text(giocatore.cognomeGiocatore)
                                Text(giocatore.ruoloGiocatore)
                                Text(giocatore.nascitaGiocatore)
                                Text(giocatore.etàGiocatore, format: .number)
                            }
                            .scaledToFit()
                        }
                    }
                }
                .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
                .frame(width: 600, height: 300)
            }
            
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem {
                Button(action: cancellaGiocatore) {
                    Label("Delete Item", systemImage: "trash")
                        .foregroundColor(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.blue/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                }
            }
        }
            .navigationTitle("Rosa")
    }
    
    private func cancellaGiocatore() {
        withAnimation {
            print("Bottone cliccato")
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I tried several ways to select one row of the grid and delete the corresponding values, but not able to achieve any valuable result.

How can I handle this?

Thanks,
A.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc19/204